# Issue with coding, how do I fix this?

Tags: html, css

How do I move the text "WELCOME TO MY PORTFOLIO" up?

[Example of my coding/site.](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/WRJaXO)

Here is my code:

```
.title4 {
    text-align:middle;
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color:white;
    font-size:45pt;
    font-size:2.5em;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0;
}

.part1{
    margin-top:120px;
}
.part2{
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, the best way to learn technology is by a process commonly known as *research*. In order to be able to post this question, you actually had to click through a bunch of screens with tips and how-to's about [ask], including advice to research the answer to your question. The most common method of researching is searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to reduce `margin-top` value of `.part1`?

You should put `<h1>`,`<h1>` inside div

```
<section class="one">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title4 part1">WELCOME TO MY</h1>
    <h1 class="title4 part2">PORTFOLIO</h1>
  </div>
</section>

.one {position:relative;}
.container {
  position:absolute;
  /*control the postition of the container div by left=,bottom=,top=,right=*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a negative margin is one way:

```
.one{
  margin-top:-50px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a margin-top pushing it down, just change the margin-top for the .part1 class from 120px to something lower like 80px;

```
.part1 {
/* margin-top:120px;  This line is causing it to lower. */
   margin-top:80px;
}
```